# gridview_RowCommand firing two times

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am performing database update call by clicking on a button which resides on a gridview.
It works fine it updates the database properly but the problem is that when i refresh the page it again perform the same operation(db update) i.e again call the RowCommand Event of Gridview.

Here is my short code view:

```
protected void gridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {   
            if (e.CommandName == "lnkBtn1")
            {
                 userDetails obj=new userDetails();
                 bool flag=obj.Updatuser();
                 if (flag)
                 {
                    lblSucess.Visible = true;

                  //this will binds updated table to grid 
                    this.BindGrid();
                 }
                  else
                 {
                 lblError.visible=true;
                 }
            }
       }
```

Comment: Replace your linkbutton with anchor tag , then see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug, there is the work around

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/102115/gridview-rowcommand-event-firing-twice

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, grid bind function is called each time page is loaded....

Comment: yes gridbind call at each page load,but RowCommand is want to be call at only buttonclick instead it call twice.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I solved it by using OnClick event of the Button inside gridview instead of RowCommand.

Visit below link:
[GridView RowCommand Event is firing twice in UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364671/gridview-rowcommand-event-is-firing-twice-in-updatepanel/12366746#12366746)